# Python - parsing a line when it match, with specific formula

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have some real time packets coming as below stored in a file `log.log`, and i am reading the `log.log` file as `tail -f` and parsing it. But all the lines are random with no fixed values, such as random ip, random values in `data::blocks`, each data:: is a column values. e.g in a `log.log`

```
Ohter type of lines...
[TCP]: incomeing data: 91 bytes, data=connect data::10.109.0.200data::10.109.0.86data::wandata::p4data::1400data::800data::end
[TCP]: incomeing data: 91 bytes, data=connect data::10.109.0.201data::10.109.8.86data::landata::p4data::1400data::700data::end
[TCP]: incomeing data: 91 bytes, data=connect data::10.109.0.200data::10.109.58.86data::3gdata::p4data::400data::800data::end
something.. else...
```

Now, How can i parse the line? where it can ignore anything and only parse when this match:

```
connect data::ANYdata::ANYdata::ANYdata::ANYdata::ANYdata::ANYdata::end
```

Run:

```
$ tail -f /var/tmp/log.log | python -u /var/tmp/myparse.py
```

myparse.py:

```
import sys, time, os, subprocess
import re

def p(command):
  subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line:
    if "command:start" in line:
      print "OK - working"
      p("/var/tmp/single_thread_process.sh")  

    if "connect data::" in line:
      ..

    else:
      # ^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$ Parse the 0032, 32, +32
      #match = re.search(r'^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', line)
      #if match:
        #print "OK"

      ### NOT working ### 
      match = re.search(r'^connect data::*data::*data::*data::*data::*data::*data::end$', line)
      if match:
        print "OK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
match = re.search(r'connect data::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::end$', line)
```

The beginning of line anchor `^` is the first thing that's preventing the matches.

Also `*` is not a wildcard in regex, it's a quantifier meaning 0 or more times. You can use `[^:]+` to mean 'any character except colons'.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pN6vJ0)

Comment: +1. The regex can be simplified by quantifying the subpattern: `r'connect data::([^:]+::){6}end$'`.

Comment: @FMc Yup. I initially just wanted to change as little as possible from OP's current regex, and then forgot about that repetition ^^; Thanks for mentioning it!